# Visual studio branches

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure

In our company we are developing a normal ASP.Net application.
Now we need to transfer the application to a cloud application that will run under Windows Azure.
So we will have two version of the application

Normal installation on IIS
Runs under Windows Azure
My question is that how to manage the TFS branches. Should I create two TFS branches foreach version and do each change 2 times or is there an alternative way to handle this problem?

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We did one of the project like this, where two versions of the application (regular IIS deployment and Azure) have to be maintained in parallel. Although there were substantial differences between the two versions, we used one single code base. This worked out pretty good, I think we would have more problems if we decided to go with branches.

Few hints to make it easier to use one single code base accross legacy and Azure deployments:

**1:** Differences in behavior in the code is easy to do with dynamic check

```
if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)  
{  
   // Azure specific code  
}
else 
{
    // normal IIS code
}
```

Any differences in UI could be done this way by hiding/unhiding elements from the page.

**2:** Create separate project and solution configurations for a) IIS production deployment, b) IIS debuging, c) Azure production and d) DevFabric. Use  web.config transforms to get around any differnces in web.config.

**3:** For debugging under DevFabric the base version (i.e. non-transformed version) of web.config is used. I found it easier to make your base web.config to be used unmodified for DevFabric environment (i.e. the transform you would create for DevFabric would be empty). This makes debugging under DevFabric easy. The side effect is that it makes it impossible to debug under Callipso. As a workaround for Callipso problem, setup normal IIS on your dev box and use WebDeploy to publish your package built using IIS debug configuration to local IIS instance.

Comment: +1: exactly the same approach that we followed, and this worked well. We also wrapped configuration in our own class so we could use `web.config` `app.settings` for some settings and Azure configuration for others.

Comment: I think this is the approach that we will follow.

Answer (score 2):

If the differences between the branches are small, consider using conditional compilation to switch between different platforms - this eliminates the need to branch and makes it easy to see when you're working on parts of the code that are branched. Similarly you can use abstract classes with a concrete implementation for each platform, which is a much cleaner approach than using #if on lots of small chunks of code.

If branching, then I'd use one of two approaches: if the differences are isolated, possibly consider refactoring the code to collect the differences into a small area of the codebase, and just branch that bit. Or insert a root level folder and branch there so that absolutely everything is branched.

When you make changes in one branch you will have to merge those changes across to the other branch, which is why I'd try to minimise the scope of the branches, to minimise the need to merge.